# React(redux), how to push list in list as saparated items

Tags: arrays, reactjs, list, push, state

I want to push items of a list into list of previous state.
I used immutable "List" and list.push() but, It doesn't push with separated items.

Just whole list is put in previous list state. like this.

list [(1), (2), (3)] + List [(1), (2)]

==> List [(1), (2), (3), List[(1) (2)]]

I want to get List [(1), (2), (3), (4), (5)]

push list Reducer below

```
  ...pender({
    type: PATCH_IMG,
    onSuccess: (state, action) => {
      const images = List(state.getIn(['orderById', 'images']))
      return state.setIn(['orderById', 'images'], images.push(List(action.payload.data)))
    }
```

return payload.data with fileList below (server-Nodejs)

```
router.patch('/img/:id', upload.array('images', 10), async(req, res) => {
  let fileList = [];
  for(let i = 0; i < req.files.length; i++) {
    fileList.push(`/img/${req.files[i].filename}`)
  }
  const order = await Order.findByIdAndUpdate(
    req.params.id,
    {
      $push: {"images": fileList}
    }
  )
  await res.send(fileList);
})
```

This is a screenshot before executing reducer (below link).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sOKVm.png)

This is a screenshot after executing reducer (below link).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DzbPM.png)

Comment: Try to use `concat` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat

Comment: @DarknessZX OMG It's work. Perfect. Thanks!

Comment: @DarknessZX If you post answer, I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are pushing an array to an array.

In your case you should use `concat` to merge array

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat

For example:
`images.concat(List(action.payload.data))`